# Emulating Client by sending encrypted hexdump to dB server and getting response back

Tags: encryption, server, client, decryption

So I used wireshark to retrieve a hexdump that has been encrypted with RSA.

I need to figure out what the response to that would be when it comes back from the server.

How I imagine it would work is:

I develop a program which will send the hexdump to the server, then the server sends back the response to the program which will the display the information.

The server would decrypt the info when it reaches it and I believe sends it back to the client as plain text. Even if it doesn't I feel this would be a good start.

The IP address is 54.160.125.215 and it is on port 9339

There are other IP's but for this project the one above is the one that is needed.

How would I go about doing this and what programming language??

I would very much appreciate your help and guidance in this.

Thank you

Comment: Shiv - can you please read the [about] page. I don't think you understand what this site scope is.

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting is called a [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).  If the protocol designer for *Clash of Clans* was at all competent, they included countermeasures to prevent people from doing exactly what you are trying.